# Print a trace of commands in bash without variable expansion

Tags: bash

I have a script for which I'm using `set -x` to print a trace of the commands as they are executed.

> Print a trace of simple commands, `for` commands, `case` commands, `select`
>   commands, and arithmetic `for` commands and their arguments or
>   associated word lists after they are expanded and before they are
>   executed. The value of the `PS4` variable is expanded and the resultant
>   value is printed before the command and its expanded arguments.

Is there a way to get this behaviour, but *not* print the variable expansions? I'm capturing the log output and sending it to a centralised logger, but I do not want the value of certain sensitive variables to be output.

Comment: Aside: note that if sensitive values are included in any command lines, anyone logged into the same machine can see them. Just so you're aware :)

Comment: These machines are very locked-down, so someone logged into the same host isn't what I'm trying to protect against. Instead, I just want to prevent this value showing up in the logs. I can of course do this by `grep -v`'ing the logs post-facto, but if I can stop it being output altogether, that would be preferable.

Comment: @obeattie And `grep -v` would be a hassle since there is no way of knowing the difference between expansions and fixed values: `bash -xc 'a="hello"; echo "$a" "hello"'`

Comment: Yes you're right; that would be a hassle 

Comment: Can you identify the commands that expand sensitive values?  If so, put `set +x` before them and `set -x` after to suppress the trace output from those commands.

Comment: Why is data which is stored on a sensitive system sent to a system whose users have no access to the sensitive system?!

Comment: @Kusalananda This is a build system. Some encryption keys are needed to build software, but the users of the system should not be able to see these keys. Users can view the logs but do not necessarily have access to the machine. I appreciate your concern about the security of the system as a whole, but I am asking very specifically about how to prevent expanded variables showing up in output.

Comment: Fair enough. I believe you got a good answer below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use trap DEBUG with $BASH_COMMAND like so

```
#!/bin/bash

set -T

trap 'echo "$PS4$BASH_COMMAND"' DEBUG

i=1234

echo "$i"

(echo $i)
```

This will print

```
+ i=1234
+ echo "$i"
1234
+ echo $i
1234
```

> **BASH_COMMAND**
>   The command currently being executed or about to be executed, unless the shell is executing a command as the result of a trap, in which case it is the command executing at the time of the trap.
>
> **-T**
>   If set, any traps on DEBUG and RETURN are inherited by shell functions, command substitutions, and commands executed in a subshell environment. The DEBUG and RETURN traps are normally not inherited in such cases.
>
> **trap**
>   If a sigspec is DEBUG, the command arg is executed before every simple command, for command, case command, select command, every arithmetic for command, and before the first command executes in a shell function